# Jekyll on Heroku listing additional (internal?) posts I haven't created

Tags: ruby, heroku, jekyll

Alright, I'm dealing with a really odd problem.

I've built a Jekyll-based site with several test posts. Locally, it compiles perfectly. Now I've begun testing it on Heroku (its eventual home). I'm using a [custom buildpack](https://github.com/mattmanning/heroku-buildpack-ruby-jekyll) to build the site once it is pushed to Heroku so I don't have to commit compiled content into my repo.

The Jekyll site is building without error, and yet, the results are bizarre. My index page is built to list all of my posts in `site.posts`:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

It starts with the test post I've made, and then lists 28 other "posts" that I've never created. They look to me like internal Jekyll functions somehow getting caught up in the compiler. Here are some of their names:

- Md Extension
- Text Extension
- Timezone Override
- Time Override
- Override Data
- Date Override
- Foo --- Bar
- No Yaml
- ...

These "posts" are only showing up when compiling on Heroku.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem then it occurred to me heroku run at / and gems are installed in /vendor. Once Jekyll runs it scans all the files and folders in the directory to build _site.

Edit your _config.yml and tell Jekyll exclude 'vendor'. I also have mine configured to exclude 'Procfile', 'unicorn.rb' and 'config.ru'.

Comment: Excellent catch. Fixed it for me. Thanks!